# Mysql (MariaDB) групповой UPDATE с указанием в WHERE более одного критерия

Tags: mysql, update, mariadb, case, multiset

Пишу конструктор запросов `update` для работы с СУБД `MariaDB`, с поддержкой группового обновления одним запросом и возможностью указания нескольких последовательных (`AND`) критериев обновления в `WHERE`.

С одним критерием в `WHERE` конструктор уже работает, но вот доработать его для работы с несколькими, пока не получается.

**Тестовые данные:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user_message`
(
    `fid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `new` TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    `f_hide` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `t_hide` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `message` VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
    `date` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`date`,`fid`),
    KEY(`fid`),
    KEY(`tid`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tbl_user_message`
    (`fid`,`tid`,`new`,`message`,`date`)
VALUES
    (4,1,1,'To me',1483399609),
    (1,4,1,'From me',1483399734);

SELECT * FROM `tbl_user_message`;

TRUNCATE `tbl_user_message`;
```

Текущая задача выполнить групповое обновление единственных двух строк в таблице, установив им поля `new` в DEFAULT и `t_hide` в 1, обновляя их по первичному ключу (`date` AND `fid`) каждую.

Нашёл 2 варианта решения задачи, но у меня проблема с аргументом `DEFAULT`, при этом с `NULL` работает всё нормально.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344247/6254425

```
UPDATE `tbl_user_message` SET
`new` = CASE
WHEN `date`=1483399609 AND `fid`=4 THEN DEFAULT
WHEN `date`=1483399734 AND `fid`=1 THEN DEFAULT
ELSE `new` END,
`t_hide` = CASE
WHEN `date`=1483399609 AND `fid`=4 THEN 1
WHEN `date`=1483399734 AND `fid`=1 THEN 1
ELSE `t_hide` END
WHERE `date` IN (1483399609,1483399734) AND `fid` IN (4,1);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26915648/6254425

```
UPDATE `tbl_user_message` SET
`new` = CASE
WHEN `date`=1483399609 AND `fid`=4 THEN DEFAULT
WHEN `date`=1483399734 AND `fid`=1 THEN DEFAULT
END,
`t_hide` = CASE
WHEN `date`=1483399609 AND `fid`=4 THEN 1
WHEN `date`=1483399734 AND `fid`=1 THEN 1
END
WHERE (`date`=1483399609 AND `fid`=4) OR (`date`=1483399734 AND `fid`=1);
```

**1** Почему запросы не работают с `DEFAULT` в качестве аргумента, возвращаемого `CASE`, но с `NULL` проблем нет?

P.S. Явное указание DEFAULT NULL полю `new` не решает проблему.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/case-operator

**2** Какой из этих запросов, более оптимален, надёжен, безопасен?
В одном есть `ELSE` и критерии в `WHERE` через `IN`, в другом нет `ELSE`, но критерии в `WHERE` выполнены через `AND` + `OR`.
Какая конструкция и в какой ситуации будет лучше для моего примера, учитывая мой первичный ключ?

**3**

```
UPDATE `tbl_user` SET `status`=1 WHERE `id`=1 LIMIT 1;
```

Есть ли в этом запросе хоть какая-то польза от ограничения `LIMIT 1`, с учётом того, что `id` `PRIMARY KEY`?
Есть ли вообще полза от ограничения `LIMIT` в `UPDATE`-запросах, и если есть, то в каких случаях?

Comment: дак и что эти запросы у вас делают то? если не работают

Comment: первый приведенный запрос весьма сомнителен - изначально выбрать больше данных чем надо, а потом нужные проапдейтить новым значением, а не нужные старым.

Comment: @teran Устанавливают `new` в DEFAULT и `t_hide` в 1 в двух единственных строках, обновляя их по первичному ключу (`date` AND `fid`) каждую. Вроде очевидно, но раз так добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: Вы написали, что у вас эти варианты не работают. Я спрашиваю, как именно они не работают. Обновляют лишнее, ничего, или вообще ошибку выдают.

Comment: @teran 1 #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'WHEN `date`=1483399734 AND `fid`=1 THEN DEFAULT
ELSE `new` END,
`t_hide` = CAS' на строке 4
2 #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'WHEN `date`=1483399734 AND `fid`=1 THEN DEFAULT
END,
`t_hide` = CASE
WHEN `da' на строке 4
Не уже ли у Вас они выполняются?

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/case-operator/

Comment: неужели вы думаете, что я код из каждого вопроса на SO пытаюсь где-то выполнить?

Comment: а для чего вообще писать два апдейта одним запросом, это чисто академический интерес или что?

Comment: @teran Для оптимизации производительности.

Comment: попробуйте использовать `default` с именем столбца, т.е. ``DEFAULT(`new`)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** Отказался от установки `NULL`-значений через `DEFAULT`.
Если нужно указать именно `NULL`, теперь я в php передаю `null` в качестве значения и если значение `is_null()`, то заменяю его на `NULL`.
Если данные могут поступить от полей форм, и нужно вместо пустой строки установить именно `NULL`, то предварительно перед отправкой в конструктор, заменяю все пустые строки на `null`.

**2** Объединил 2 варианта, и добавил скобки и апострофы для более удобной реализации через конструктор.

```
UPDATE `tbl_user_message` SET
`new`=CASE
WHEN (`date`='1483399609' AND `fid`='4') THEN NULL
WHEN (`date`='1483399734' AND `fid`='1') THEN NULL
ELSE `new` END,
`t_hide`=CASE
WHEN (`date`='1483399609' AND `fid`='4') THEN '1'
WHEN (`date`='1483399734' AND `fid`='1') THEN '1'
ELSE `t_hide` END
WHERE (`date`='1483399609' AND `fid`='4') OR (`date`='1483399734' AND `fid`='1');
```

**3** Как реньше никогда не использовал `LIMIT` в `UPDATE`-запросах, так и сейчас не использую.

Answer (score 2):

По [документации](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/update/) на update в mariadb указано, что в фразе `SET` запроса `update` полю таблицы можно присвоить *или* любое выражение (expresion) (под выражением понимается в том числе конструкция `case`) *или* ключевое слово DEFAULT. Т.е. слово `DEAFULT` нельзя использовать нигде, кроме непосредственного равенства поля. В отличие от него NULL - это конкретное значение, которое можно спокойно установить.

А что касается производительности, если ваш язык позволяет делать подготавливаемые запросы с подставляемыми позже параметрами, то подготовка запроса вида `update tab set x=? where id=?` и последующее многоразовое его выполнение с передачей требуемых параметров может оказаться быстрее выбранного вами способа (и не забивает SQL-кеш уникальными текстами запросов). Но и в этом случае для установки значения DEFAULT надо будет дать отдельный запрос, так как это ключевое слово и как параметр запроса его передать нельзя.

И если вы все таки хотите использовать такой множественный update, то лучшим решением (разумеется опять же не решающим проблему DEFAULT) будет запрос вида:

```
UPDATE `tbl_user_message` OLD
  JOIN (
   SELECT 1483399609 `date`, 4 fid, 1 t_hide
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1483399734 `date`, 1 fid, 1 t_hide
  ) NEW
    ON OLD.`date`=NEW.`date` and OLD.fid=NEW.fid
   SET `new`=DEFAULT, `t_hide`=NEW.t_hide
```

По крайней мере такой запрос будет давать стабильный план выполнения вне зависимости от количества изменяемых записей и будет прицельно менять только нужные записи, не захватывая посторонние, что явно быстрее чем изменение в куче посторонних записей колонки на сами себя.

И честно говоря, если всем записям надо поставить фиксированные значения, то самым простым и быстрым вариантом будет конечно:

```
UPDATE `tbl_user_message` OLD
   SET `new`=DEFAULT, t_hide=1
 WHERE (`date`,fid) IN( (1483399609,4), (1483399734,1) )
```

Что касается вашего третьего вопроса, я не вижу никакого выигрыша от `limit 1` кроме случая если заданный ключ окажется не уникальным ключом.

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение с DEFAULT, буду думать, как обходится без него, и, возможно, указывать NULL явно.
> что явно быстрее чем изменение в куче посторонних записей колонки на сами себя.
Если я правильно понял, то в обоих моих запросах условие WHERE этому препятствует и затрагиваются только нужные записи.
С prepare пробовал, но в php очень криво реализовано привязка параметров к запросу, да и DEFAULT/NULL передавать нельзя.
По поводу limit я тоже не вижу пользу от него, но в SELECT-запросе, например `SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1`, где id PK, он же как-то помогает?

Comment: @IlyaIndigo Ну в первом вашем варианте `where date IN (1483399609,1483399734) AND fid IN (4,1)` под обновление попадет запись с date=1483399609 и fid=1 (ну и с вторым временем аналогично), чего явно не задумывалось. В select никакого выигрыша от limit в этом случае нет

Comment: @IlyaIndigo Кстати, зачем вам DEFAULT, я не сталкивался с ситуациями когда колонки при update надо было бы поставить именно DEFAULT значение объявленное при создании таблицы

Comment: @IlyaIndigo И еще кстати, чем вам привязываемые параметры не нравятся, мне вот вариант с передачей массива значений прямо в PDO::execute очень даже нравится. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php  да и null там можно передать, как значение null привязываемой переменной.

Comment: DEFAULT мне нужно для NULL полей. Явно NULL через PHP не задашь, и указание NULL поля на поле без NULL выдаст ошибку. Придумал такой хак в конструкторе запроса все пустые строки заменять на DEFAULT, что для NULL устанавливает в NULL, а NOT NULL устанавливает в '', если на поле DEFAULT не переопределён. А теперь буду думать, скорее всего через POST-запросы NULL прокидывать не понадобится, буду .заменять не пустые строки на DEFAULT, а явно тип null на NULL,
А поля с NULL очень удобно использовать для подсчёта, например новых сообщений, так как COUNT и прочие агрегатные ф-ии их игнорируют.

Comment: Мне вот это безобразие не понравилось.
https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
Никогда с PDO не работал, благодарю буду иметь ввиду. :-)

Comment: @IlyaIndigo Я бы предоставил использующему движок самому решать ставить null или `''`. по крайней мере мне бы очень не понравился движок который бы за меня решал, что назначить полю. Поля not null для того и придуманы, что бы выдавать ошибку при занесении null значения, после которых программист явно видит, что он чего то не учел и в БД не висят годами скрытые ошибки с пустыми значениями где они не допустимы

Comment: От части с вами согласен, но всё же поля с NOT NULL нужны в первую очередь для того, чтобы не использовать NULL, если оно не нужно.
Вот вспомнил случай, когда есть куча разных строк, не все из которых могут быть заполнены, а их все нужно конкатинировать с разделителем. CONCAT_WS игнорирует NULL, а на пустые строки ставит разделители. А GET/POST передаёт только строки, и явно null никак не передать через форму, придётся в таком случае самому до конструктора пустые строки null-ами заменять, а так конструктор сам на DEFAULT менял, подставляя NULL.

Comment: @IlyaIndigo А если в таблице будет поле позволяющее NULL и при этом с `DEFAULT 'abc'` будет очень интересно посмотреть как вы в него NULL будете заносить ...

Comment: Ну для этого мне будет нужно самому себе выстрелить в ногу, так как решение о том, NULL это поле или нет и изменять ли DEFAULT принимаю я сам. И DEFAULT в БД я не люблю переопределять, уж лучше в коде исправить.