# Использовать значение из MYSQL в PHP, который включен в MYSQL запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется следующая функция, которая отлично работает:

```
function update_currencies_rates($currency_rate)
{
    
    $this->db->set('main_rate', 'CASE
   
    WHEN type = "Fiat main" THEN ' . $currency_rate["BTC-USD"]["ask"] . '
    
    END', FALSE);
    
    $this->db->set('last_update_time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    
    $this->db->update('currencies');
    
}
```

`$currency_rate` это JSON-массив с множеством курсов различных валют

Но вместо `USD` в `$currency_rate["BTC-USD"]["ask"]` нужно использовать значение из столбца под названием `code` из таблицы MYSQL, в котором находятся коды валют каждой из строк. Таким образом, хотелось бы добиться того, чтобы при UPDATE в MYSQL в каждую строку этой таблицы из JSON-массива добавлялись бы курсы в соответствии с валютой этой строки, код которой находится в столбце `code`.

Пробовал примерно так, но это не работает:

```
WHEN type = "Fiat main" THEN ' . $currency_rate["BTC- . ' code ' . "]["ask"] . '
```

Как можно это осуществить?

Comment: mysql и php живут каждый своей жизнью. такой прямой обмен, как вы его видите невозможен. Либо придется читать из таблицы обычным select валюты и потом на каждый давать update. Либо загнать сразу весь массив из php внутрь одного запроса, что бы он все это сделал на стороне mysql как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642061 например

Comment: И не знаю что там писал Akina, но да, структура хранения и другие подробности позволили бы привести более оптимальное решение для конкретной ситуации. Вы пытаетесь спросить как решить задачу именно выбранным вам способом, который не жизнеспособен и требуется видеть изначальную задачу, что бы выбрать рабочее решение

Comment: @Mike, благодарю за развернутый комментарий!